# iOS UISlider in UIAlertView

Tags: ios, uialertview, uislider

I know that there has been one question about this but it is not clear to me. I want to add a UISlider to UIAlertView. In the UIAlertView, I also add one UILabel to show the value of UISlider. What I have been done so far is:

```
            UIAlertView *alert= [[UIAlertView alloc]
                    initWithTitle: @"Set delay"
                    message: @" "
                    delegate: nil
                    cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                    otherButtonTitles:nil];
            UISlider *mySlider=[[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 50, 200, 20)];
            mySlider.maximumValue=10.00;
            mySlider.minimumValue=1.00;
            UILabel *myLabel=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(220, 50, 50, 40)];
            int x=.........;//x should get value of mySlider
            [myLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",x]];
            [alert addSubview:myLabel];
            [alert addSubview:mySlider];            
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
```

so I want variable `x` to get value of `mySlider` and the `myLabel` will show the value of `x`. I get stuck at this point. Any suggestion is really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here what you need to do:

1. Make the `UILabel` global, that mean declare it on the header file (this is to reach the label easily).
2. Then add a target to the slider, with `ValueChanged` event.

   ```
   [mySlider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderHandler:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
   ```
3. next, implement the `sliderHandler` method:

   ```
   - (void) sliderHandler: (UISlider *)sender {
        int x = sender.value;
        [myLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"value = %d",x]];
   }
   ```

That will work with you.